# Is it possible to rolling over a page to its back with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

It's a little hard to describe, hope I can make it clear:

I have a button in `page-1`, when user click this button, I want the browser **Roll Over** to `page-2`.

`Roll Over` means the page's **right side go far away** and **left side come close to me**. The result is this `page`'s back side displayed.

Is there any library could do this ?

Comment: You mean you want to flip the page and show a mirror image?

Comment: Check out if any of these are of use? - http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/12/best-jquery-page-flip-book-effect-with-examples/